# Change Fragment width in Orientation change

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm currently learning Android Studio development and I'm stumbled with a tutorial's exercise (Stuck for almost 2 weeks).
It required me to use Fragment to create this appearance :

[See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDsSJ.jpg)

Here is my code :

home.java

```
public class home extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        Intent previousIntent = getIntent();
        String username = previousIntent.getStringExtra("username");

        Bundle sendDataToBody = new Bundle();
        sendDataToBody.putString("username", username);

        // Fragment

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        WindowManager windowManager = getWindowManager();
        Point size = new Point();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
            windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size);

            if (size.x > size.y) {
                // landscape

                Menu fragmentMenu = new Menu();
                body fragmentBody = new body();

                fragmentBody.setArguments(sendDataToBody);

                fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.menuFrame, fragmentMenu);
                fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.bodyFrame, fragmentBody);
            } else {
                // portrait

                Menu fragmentMenu = new Menu();
                fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.menuFrame, fragmentMenu);
            }
        } else {
            Display display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();

            if (display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_90
                    || display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_270) {
                // landscape


                Menu fragmentMenu = new Menu();
                body fragmentBody = new body();

                fragmentBody.setArguments(sendDataToBody);

                fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.menuFrame, fragmentMenu);
                fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.bodyFrame, fragmentBody);
            } else {
                //portrait
                Menu fragmentMenu = new Menu();
                fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.menuFrame, fragmentMenu);
            }
        }

        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        // End of Fragment
    }
}
```

and my home.xml :

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:paddingTop="@dimen/container_padding_vertical"
       android:paddingBottom="@dimen/container_padding_vertical"
       android:paddingRight="@dimen/container_padding_horizontal"
       android:paddingLeft="@dimen/container_padding_horizontal"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       tools:context=".home">

       <FrameLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:id="@+id/menuFrame"></FrameLayout>


       <FrameLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:id="@+id/bodyFrame"></FrameLayout>

   </LinearLayout>
```

As you can see, 
If I run these codes, in portrait mode it work as the picture.

But when I change the orientation to landscape,
The Button still go fullscreen.

How can I change the button to be only some part like the picture ?

Note : this is my first Q in stackOverflow about android. I hope my explanation is clear enough

**Edit**

Here is my menuFragment.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      tools:context=".Menu">

      <Button
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/convertBtn"
          android:text="Convert USD/IDR" />

      <Button
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/logoutBtn"
          android:text="Logout"/>

  </LinearLayout>
```

Here is my bodyFragment.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".body">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/username_show"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: show me your fragment xml code

Comment: Hi Mr. Patel, thanks for answering. May I know why u want to see the fragment XML code ?, In my understanding, fragment is like iframe in HTML, no ?... So the container is matter, not the inside. Am I wrong ?, thanks in advanced.

Comment: I'll post a solution in sometime stay tuned

Comment: check out my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do here is use the *Resources Framework* to provide two different layouts for each of your Fragments and your Activity. One layout will be for portrait orientation, and the other will be for landscape orientation.

The structure will look like this:

```
res/
    layout/
        activity_home.xml
        fragment_body.xml
        fragment_menu.xml
    layout-land/
        activity_home.xml
        fragment_body.xml
        fragment_menu.xml
```

You don't have to do anything in your code. Just use `setContentView(R.layout.activity_home)` in your Activity and the correct version (portrait or landscape) will be selected automatically for you.

Similarly, in your Fragments you can write `inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_body, parent, false)` and the correct version will be selected automatically for you.

Now, you just have to make sure that your different xml files do what you want. For example, in the portrait one you can make your buttons match the screen width:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    .../>

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    .../>
```

But then in your landscape one you can make your buttons wrap:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    .../>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    .../>
```

As long as you use the same `id`s in the landscape and portrait versions, everything will "just work".

Comment: Thanks Ben, but why only `layout-land` ?, how about the portrait ?, will it use the default in `layout` folder ?

Comment: It works !, thanks Ben... but new problem arise, the onClick event is gone after the orientation change... The button is clickable, but nothing happen.

Comment: For your first question: `layout` is the "default" layout directory, so it will catch all cases that you don't explicitly specify. Since we're explicitly using `layout-land` for our landscape files, we use `layout` for portrait. We could instead use `layout-port` for portrait and `layout` for landscape if we wanted, but by convention we use `layout-land` + `layout`.

Comment: For your second question, I don't see anything in the original post about onClick events. At this point, probably the best course of action is to open a new question to ask about the onClick events. If you link the new question here, I'd be happy to take a look.

Comment: No problem, I'll go find the answer first on stackOverflow so there would be no double question. Anyway, thanks man for the help, appreciate it so much.